# Brew doctor continuous errors

Tags: macos, command-line, terminal, homebrew

I ran the brew doctor command after brew not working so I followed the steps and I tried chowning all of the errors and delete them, but would not work no matter what I did.

```
Coles-MacBook-Pro:~ coleschiffer$ brew doctor
Warning: /Users/coleschiffer/Library/Logs/Homebrew isn't writable.
This can happen if you "sudo make install" software that isn't managed
by Homebrew.

Homebrew writes debugging logs to this location.

You should probably `chown` /Users/coleschiffer/Library/Logs/Homebrew

Warning: Unbrewed dylibs were found in /usr/local/lib.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected dylibs:
    /usr/local/lib/libntfs-3g.80.dylib
    /usr/local/lib/libntfs.9.0.0.dylib
    /usr/local/lib/libublio.1.dylib

Warning: Unbrewed .la files were found in /usr/local/lib.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected .la files:
    /usr/local/lib/libntfs-3g.la
    /usr/local/lib/libntfs.la
    /usr/local/lib/libublio.la

Warning: Unbrewed .pc files were found in /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected .pc files:
    /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/libntfs-3g.pc
    /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/libublio.pc

Warning: Unbrewed static libraries were found in /usr/local/lib.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected static libraries:
    /usr/local/lib/libntfs-3g.a
    /usr/local/lib/libntfs.a
    /usr/local/lib/libublio.a
Coles-MacBook-Pro:~ coleschiffer$
```

Thanks a lot for you taking your time to help and/or read this.

Comment: Brew said you can delete the libs in /usr/local/lib/. The chmod you must to because brew is not the owner of /Users/coleschiffer/Library/Logs/Homebrew.

Comment: what should I do thanks I been trying to install rails on osx maveric for two days now just a bunch of errors. Thanks for the help

Comment: What you can try to do is: 1) execute in the terminal: rm files_indicated_by_brew and 2) chown coleschiffer:staff /Users/coleschiffer/Library/Logs/Homebrew .

Comment: Thanks so much and sorry I really not good at this, but I am not sure which files were indicated by brew

Comment: The files below the lines: Unexpected dylibs/la/.pc/static libraries: